# Kinetic: Problems during installation of turtlebot_Simulator

Tags: ros, simulation, installation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I was trying to install the binaries of the  turtlebot_Simulator by the follwing way.

**1) Installation by binarys of  turtlebot-simulator**

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator

**2) move files of packet to "src" folder**

I tried before I get the hint to use the binaries, directly the source code "src" of my
workspace "turtlebot_ws"

I also installed the source code package of turtlebot_simulator.
git clone https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator.git

**3)Following files are now in the folder (inkl. turtlebot_simulator.git )**

~/turtlebot_ws$ ls src

CMakeLists.txt   setup_kobuki.sh    turtlebot_capabilities             turtlebot.rosinstall

README.md        turtlebot          turtlebot_capabilities.rosinstall  turtlebot_simulator

setup_create.sh  turtlebot_bringup  turtlebot_description              turtlebot_teleop

**4) Compile the package**

Enter the command: ~/turtlebot_ws$ catkin_make

**5) Trying to start**

When I trying to start the simulator, I get the following error message:

~/turtlebot_ws$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

... logging to /home/ros/.ros/log/ebc2837c-60cb-11e7-baaa-000c29a91528/roslaunch-ubuntu-4167.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid  tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE' is not set.

Arg xml is

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**6) Here are my ROS Variables:**

**printenv | grep ROS**

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ros/turtlebot_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/ros/turtlebot_ws/devel/share/common-lisp

ROS_DISTRO=kinetic

ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros

**Same for the turtle bot variables:**

**printenv | grep TURTLE**

TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=asus_xtion_pro

TURTLEBOT_STACKS=hexagons

TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION=false

TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_WHITELIST=[rocon_apps, turtlebot_rapps]

TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT=/dev/kobuki

TURTLEBOT_BASE=kobuki

TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_BLACKLIST=[]

TURTLEBOT_TYPE=turtlebot

TURTLEBOT_BATTERY=/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0

TURTLEBOT_INTERACTIONS_LIST=[turtlebot_bringup/admin.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/documentation.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/pairing.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/visualisation.interactions]

TURTLEBOT_NAME=turtlebot

I do not know, if it is a failure to try install the binaries and the source code version ?

Later I would like to modify the source code to lern more about the system. Therefore, the goal for
me would be to install and get run the source code version.

I am new in ROS and trying to get a foot into the door and need help.

Best regards
Ritchie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265427/kinetic:-problems-during-installation-of-turtlebot_simulator-../) by [Ritchie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31015/ritchie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess I found the problem first problem by myself.

I enter the follwong command

**export TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE=~/turtlebot_ws/src/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world**

And now it starts.

Best regards
R.

---

Originally posted by [Ritchie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31015/ritchie/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0